# Simple integral extension question

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

> If $R$ is a commutative ring, why is every $x$ in $R$ integral over $R$?

I can't see what monic polynomial will have $x$ as a root.

Comment: Look at *concrete* examples, e.g. take $\,R = \Bbb Z.\,$ Given $\,n\in\Bbb Z\,$ we seek a monic $\,f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ with $\,f(n) = 0.\,$ By the Factor Theorem $\,f(n) = 0\iff x-n\mid f(x),\,$ so we can choose $\,f(x) = \,\ldots\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the polynomial $f(T)=T-x\in R[T]$?